# When i run the telegram filter bot in my vps i have got this error

Tags: bots, telegram, codeblocks

```
File "/root/AutoFilterMKNProfessorstt/info.py", line 36, in <module>
    CHANNELS = [int(ch) if id_pattern.search(ch) else ch for ch in environ.get('CHANNELS', '-1001759xxxxxx', '-1001996xxxxxx', '-1002089xxxxxx').split()]
TypeError: Mapping.get() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

info.py is the where my bot running details stored like chaneels, admins id, database url...

These are my telegram channels id (-1002089xxxxx).. xxxx mean any number is there. when i run the that bot in my vps i have got these errors. how can i fix it?